# Suppose a box contains six blue and four red balls. Five balls are selected at random w/o replacement, determine the probability mass function

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I know this question is pretty basic, but I am just not getting the right answer no matter what I try. My thought was that the answer should be like:
5C4/(10C5) for 4 red balls selected, (5C3)/(10C5) for 3 red balls selected, down to (5C0)/(10C5) for 0 red balls selected. When I do this, my answers never add up to 1, as is necessary for a probability mass function. What am I missing?

Comment: Please use Mathjax formatting. See [reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

This is a hypergeometric distribution.  Here is a simple example.  Suppose I wanted to know the probability of getting three red balls.  You wrote $$\frac{\binom{5}{3}}{\binom{10}{5}}$$ but this is wrong; the correct answer is $$\frac{\binom{4}{3} \binom{6}{2}}{\binom{10}{5}}.$$  Why?  Think of the $10$ balls as being labeled like this:
$$B_1, B_2, B_3, B_4, B_5, B_6, R_1, R_2, R_3, R_4.$$  Each ball has a distinct label.  Now say we want to pick five of them without replacement so that exactly three of the five are chosen from the balls labeled $R_1, R_2, R_3, R_4$ (so they are "red"), and the other two balls would be chosen from the $B$-labeled balls (so they are "blue").  There are obviously $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to pick the $R$-labeled balls, since there are $4$ such balls in the group and you want to pick exactly $3$ of them.  Similarly there are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to pick the $B$-labeled balls.  And those choices are independent in the sense that they each lead to a distinct choice for the five balls chosen in total.  So their product $\binom{4}{3}\binom{6}{2}$ is the numerator of our probability and counts the total number of ways to choose $5$ balls out of the $10$ such that exactly $3$ are red.  Then the denominator is just $\binom{10}{5}$ as you wrote, for the number of ways to choose $5$ balls with no restriction.

You can easily generalize this counting argument for every possible outcome of $0$ to $4$ red balls chosen.  Even though you are picking $5$ balls, since there are only $4$ red balls in the group, it is impossible to get $5$ red balls.  Now check that the probabilities add up to $1$.